# Can I list all characters not matching a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that has different ranges included, like `a-f` and `&-9`. Is there a way to list all characters included in this range, or to put it the other way around, characters that are not included? I would like to write a spec for each character allowed by my regex.

Comment: Given a string like `"a-f"`, it is easy to list all characters corresponding to it, but to parse an arbitrary regex is not that easy.

Comment: “I would like to write a spec for each character allowed by my regex”—OMG. Why would you want to test a ruby regexp engine in the first place?

Comment: i dont want to test regex engine. i want to write specific tests for speciifc characters that are not supposed be allowed in my app, and that should be COVERED by regex

Comment: Unicode 10.0 defines 136,690 characters, do you want to list all of them? ;-)

Comment: do you mean something like `("a".."f").to_a | ("&".."9").to_a #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "
3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along this:

```
(0..0x02FFFF).each do |codepoint|
  begin
    character = codepoint.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
    # .... Test your regexp here
  rescue RangeError
    # Ignore gaps in codepoint
  end
end
```

As @Stefan said in his comment: You will test quite some amount of characters with this....

BUG FIXED, thanks to Stefan

FIXED: Dealing with gaps in the Unicode code point range. Note that I omitted the Unicode planes 3-16 in my solution.

Comment: Funny, but the loop fails at the first invalid codepoint which is not necessarily the last one. BTW, it should be `codepoint += 1`

Comment: @Stefan: Isn't the codepoint range contiguous??? I wonder how we then could determine that we have exhausted all possibilities... This is more tricky than I thought.

Comment: @Stefan : Just checked [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks). There are indeed gaps!

Comment: The Unicode characters are grouped in _planes_ and each plane can contain several _blocks_.  The codepoints in a plane and in a block are contiguous and non-overlapping, but not all codepoints define a character, e.g. the [Greek and Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic) block only defines 135 out of 144 possible characters. In addition, some codepoints may be reserved, like U+D800, the one which makes your script fail.

Comment: _"I wonder how we then could determine that we have exhausted all possibilities"_ – if you really wanted to traverse all defined characters, you should probably refer to the [Unicode Character Database](http://unicode.org/ucd/).

Comment: @Stefan : I updated my solution. Do you think this would do the trick?

Comment:  for your effort, but I doubt this is what the OP had in mind ;-)